# get possible enum values for field from model to view

Tags: mysql, enums, sails.js, waterline

I have defined my model with this field

```
base: {
  type: 'string',
  in: ['A', 'B', 'C']
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way I could get the possible enum values to use in the view  for a dropdown or if I need to have the it hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to set `in` dynamically, or just asking if there's a way to retrieve the value of `in` later on?

Comment: retrieve the in values later on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always retrieve the attributes of a model with `<model>.attributes`.  For example, given:

```
// api/models/Foo.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    base: {
      type: 'string',
      in: ['A', 'B', 'C']
    }
  }
};
```

You can access `Foo.attributes.base.in` or `sails.models.foo.base.in` later to retrieve the `in` values.